# Sampling from a normal distribution using a for loop

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, normal-distribution

So I am trying to sample from a uniform distribution 1000 times each time computing the mean of 20 random samples from said uniform distribution.

```
Now let's loop through 1000 times, sampling 20 values from a uniform distribution and computing the mean of the sample, saving this mean to a variable called sampMean within a tibble called uniformSampleMeans.
{r 2c}

unif_sample_size = 20 # sample size
n_samples = 1000 # number of samples

# set up q data frame to contain the results
uniformSampleMeans <- tibble(sampMean = runif(n_samples, unif_sample_size))


# loop through all samples.  for each one, take a new random sample, 
# compute the mean, and store it in the data frame

for (i in 1:n_samples){
  uniformSampleMeans$sampMean[i] = summarize(uniformSampleMeans = mean(unif_sample_size))
}
```

I successfully generate a tibble, however the values are "NaN". Additionally when I get to my for loop I get an error.

```
Error in summarise_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're saying "normal distribution" in the main body of your post (twice) but use `runif` to sample from a *uniform* distribution. Is that a typo?

Comment: For random sampling from uniform distribution (`runif()`), you need three arguments: number of samples `n`, minimum `min`, and maximum `max`. You can't generate random samples from `runif()` with just two arguments.

Comment: @AdamB., `runif(1,-1)` works without error.

Comment: Didn't know that, cheers. I just realize `runif(1)` also works. But those seem to be very specific defaults - e.g. `runif(1000, 20)` doesn't work, and even if it did (using the same logic as `runif(1, -1)` does), it wouldn't do what @Salma Abdel-Raheem seems to want it to do

Comment: yes this is a typo, apologies it is from a uniform distribution.  I've updated my post to reflect the question my prof posted on the homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you've tagged this as a `dplyr` question, you can use `summarise_all`:

```
library(dplyr)

n_obs = 20 
n_samples = 1000 

samples <- data.frame(matrix(runif(n_obs * n_samples), nrow = 20))

summarise_all(samples, mean)
```

As others have noted, it's possible to do this in base R, too.

**Update** Per OP comment
Yes, possible to use a for loop, although not advisable.  Here's one approach:

```
unif_sample_size = 20 
n_samples = 1000 
total_draws <- unif_sample_size * n_samples

uniformSampleMeans <- 
  tibble(draw_from_uniform = runif(n_samples * unif_sample_size))

sample_means <- vector(length = n_samples)

i <- 1
for (ix in seq(1, total_draws, by = unif_sample_size)) {
  start <- ix
  end <- ix + unif_sample_size - 1
  sample_means[i] <- mean(uniformSampleMeans$draw_from_uniform[start:end])
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this using the for loop?

Comment: Salma, there are so many reasons that something like this should *not* be done with a `for` loop. But, as is often the case, "yes". One of the harder things to learn when learning a new programming language is to not project efficiencies and assumptions from other languages onto the current language. In this case, `for` loops, though not evil, are not always the idiomatic or even most-efficient way to do things in R. Please open your mind a little to different ways of looking at and and processing the data.

Answer (score 3):

Building a `data.frame` row-by-row is horrible in performance (it makes a complete copy of all rows each time you add one ... so that row 900, adding a row you have the original 900 rows *twice* ... this scales poorly).

Also, realize that taking many small random samples is a lot more expensive than taking just one larger sample.

```r
set.seed(42)
m <- matrix(rnorm(1000*20), ncol = 20)
head(m)
#        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]    [,6]   [,7]    [,8]    [,9]   [,10]  [,11]   [,12]
# [1,]  1.371  2.325  0.251 -0.686 -0.142  0.0712  0.173  1.4163 -0.0575 -0.9221  1.163 -0.2945
# [2,] -0.565  0.524 -0.278 -0.793 -0.814  0.9703 -1.273  0.5572 -0.2490 -0.4958 -0.190  0.4641
# [3,]  0.363  0.971 -1.725 -0.407 -0.326  0.3100 -0.868  0.9812 -1.5242 -3.1105 -0.289 -1.5371
# [4,]  0.633  0.377 -2.007 -1.149  0.378 -0.1395  0.626 -0.5862  0.4636 -0.6928 -0.399  0.9862
# [5,]  0.404 -0.996 -1.292  1.116 -1.994 -0.3263 -0.106  0.9392 -1.1876  0.2989  0.709  0.6302
# [6,] -0.106 -0.597  0.366 -0.879 -0.999 -0.1188 -0.256 -0.0647  0.4941 -0.0687 -1.623  0.0573
#        [,13]    [,14]    [,15]  [,16]  [,17]  [,18]   [,19]  [,20]
# [1,]  0.0538 -1.80043 -2.29607 -1.020  0.496  0.110  1.0251  1.790
# [2,]  0.7534 -0.10643  0.00465 -0.754  0.519 -0.741 -1.4492 -0.262
# [3,]  0.2499  1.83347 -1.61634 -1.226 -0.422 -0.511  1.4175 -1.297
# [4,] -0.4441  1.02390  1.73313 -1.017  0.863 -0.912 -1.0353  0.618
# [5,] -0.0503 -0.00429 -0.67368  1.722 -0.778 -1.293  0.0853 -0.292
# [6,] -0.4678  2.27991 -0.09442  3.000  0.148  0.905  0.2451 -0.301
m2 <- apply(m, 1, mean)
length(m2)
# [1] 1000
head(m2)
# [1]  0.1513 -0.2089 -0.4366 -0.0339 -0.1544  0.0959
mean(m[1,])
# [1] 0.151
tibble(i = seq_along(m2), mu = m2)
# # A tibble: 1,000 x 2
#        i      mu
#    <int>   <dbl>
#  1     1  0.151 
#  2     2 -0.209 
#  3     3 -0.437 
#  4     4 -0.0339
#  5     5 -0.154 
#  6     6  0.0959
#  7     7  0.105 
#  8     8 -0.503 
#  9     9  0.0384
# 10    10 -0.175 
# # ... with 990 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dplyr for this.

```
rep<-1000
size<-20

# initialize the dataframe
res<-data.frame(rep=NA,mean=NA)

for ( i in 1:rep) {
        samp<-rnorm(size) # here you actually create your sample of 20 numbers from the normal distribution
        res[i,]$rep<-i #save in the first column the number of the replicate sampling (optional)
        res[i,]$mean<-mean(samp) # here you calculate the mean of the random sample and store it into the datafra
}
res
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is generate 1000 replications of a sample from random uniform distribution with 20 observations (and minimums of 0 and maximums of 1), and then take the mean of each sample, here's a concise way to do it with `tidyverse` :

```
library(tidyverse)

uniform_samples <- map(1:1000, ~ runif(20, 0, 1))
uniform_sample_means <- map_dbl(uniform_samples, ~ mean(.x))
```

Comment: Why do you need `tidyverse`? While you could do it base only (`lapply`), for this you can get by with `purrr`.

Comment: 1) I prefer using formulas whenever possible, they make things clear and concise, and afaik `lapply()` doesn't support them. 2) I've just tried to solve the problem with `lapply()`, and it won't accept the 1:1000 vector without wanting to use it as `n`. So instead, I had to use `lapply(rep(20, 1000), runif, min = 0, max = 1)`, which just seems less elegant to me. 3) To get the vector of means (instead of a list), I'd have to use `sapply()` and sapply is pretty well known for being inconsistent.

Comment: `lapply(1:3, runif, n = 20, min = -1)`. `lapply` and `sapply` default to the first argument, but you can make them use the first unspecified argument if you assign the others. I don't disagree about expression-functions, I fund them much more concise. Half of my discussion was loading all dozens of packages of `tidyverse` merely for two functions. Realize that not every can install `tidyverse` (policy or other reasons), or they want to try this and have to sit through a really long compile time just to test out two functions. Consider just `library(purrr)`.

Comment: Heck, `replicate(1000, runif(20, 1, 2))` or `replicate(1000, runif(20,1,2), simplify=FALSE)` work just as well.

Comment: Fair points all around, I just think that `tidyverse` is worth it for the beginners, even with any extra hassle, because it teaches workflows that generalize easily. Base R might be more efficient computationally, but I think Hadley Wickham makes a good point in saying that, nowadays, the average programming bottleneck is rarely found in the code itself & more often between the keyboard & the chair. What do you think?

Comment: I understand, and it for many a contentious discussion. I don't have all of tidyverse installed (though I use `dplyr`, `tidyr` daily), likely never will, and I have seen many beginners who don't, either. The first-time compile time on any OS is daunting right there, our society of immediate gratification doesn't really deal well with that :-) Bottom line, it's your choice, thanks for the discourse.

Comment: I use `purrr` periodically, but rarely is there much more utility than aesthetics (e.g., `~` functions) for me; and while I agree wholeheartedly in `sapply`'s fickleness, I am quite defensive about my use of base `*apply` functions. `stringr` is decent, but I have yet to find something that isn't almost directly done with `gsub` or `gregexpr`/`regmatches`. Perhaps I'm missing out? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯